# $K_\star$ and $L_\star$ are homotopic as chain complex. Is it true that $H_\star(\operatorname{Hom}(K_\star,L_\star))$ trivial?

Tags: abstract-algebra, homological-algebra

Consider $K_\star,L_\star$ 2 chain complexes and suppose they are homotopic say $f:K\to L$.

$\textbf{Q:}$ Consider $\operatorname{Hom}(K_\star, L_\star)$ complex and take its homology. It is clear that $[f]=0\in H_0(\operatorname{Hom}_\star(K,L))$ as $f$ is a homotopy(i.e. It is boundary of $\operatorname{Hom}_1(K_\star,L_\star)$). However, do I even know or can say $H_\star(\operatorname{Hom}(K,L))=0$? Furthermore, when do I know $H_\star(\operatorname{Hom}(K,L))=0$. I doubt I can even say $H_0(\operatorname{Hom}(K,L))=0$ in general as it might be very large.

Comment: What do you mean when you say two chain complexes are "homotopic"?  That is not standard terminology.

Comment: Let $K=L=\mathbb{Z}$ concentrated in degree zero. By freeness, the hom complex will be the ordinary hom module, and its homology will be itself

Comment: @EricWofsey I think OP means the two complexes are chain homotopy equivalent

Comment: @EricWofsey Sorry for confusion. I really should say they are equivalent by a map. Pick a map $f:K\to L$ and suppose there is another map $g:L\to K$ s.t. $f,g$ induce homotopy equivalence of chain complexes.

Answer (score 0):

It's a general fact that the 0th homology of the internal hom of chain complexes equals the homotopy classes of chain maps:
$$H_0(\underline{Hom}(L,K)) = [L,K]$$
So, $[f] = 0$ iff $f$ is nulhomotopic. If you are assuming $f$ is an equivalence then $[f] = 0 $ implies $L,K$ are contractible. Similarly, if $L\simeq K$, then the following are equivalent:

1. $H_*(\underline{Hom}(L,K)) = 0$,
2. $H_0(\underline{Hom}(L,K)) = 0$,
3. $L$ is contractible, i.e. $\text{id}_L \simeq 0$.

---

In particular, if $f$ is a homotopy equivalence it does *not* follow that $[f] = 0$.